# ExtJs: How to read GUID from server on insert into store via proxy

Tags: javascript, extjs

As per http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/row-editing.html example, I have the following code on my grid to facilitate adding new records to my store:

```
tbar: [{
        text: 'Add Rate',
        handler: function(button) {
            var myGrid = button.up('grid');
            //console.log(myGrid);
            var myPlugin = myGrid.getPlugin('rowediting');
            myPlugin.cancelEdit();

            var r = Ext.create('RateManagement.model.CountrySpecific', {
                id: '',
                hostCountryId: '',
                hostCountry: '',
                rate: 0,
                currencyId: '',
                rateTypeId: '',
                frequencyCode: '',
                perFamilyMember: '',
                familySize: 0
            });

            console.log(r);

            var store = myGrid.getStore();

            store.insert(0, r);
            myPlugin.startEdit(0, 0);
        }
    }],
```

This is my model with the proxy:

```
Ext.define('RateManagement.model.CountrySpecific', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: 
        [ 
            {name:'id', type: 'string'},
            {name:'hostCountryId', type: 'string'},   
            {name:'hostCountry', type: 'string'},         
            {name:'rate',type: 'number', useNull: true},
            {name:'currencyId', type: 'string'},
            {name:'rateTypeId', type:'string'},
            {name:'frequencyCode', type:'string'},
            {name:'perFamilyMember'},
            {name:'familySize', type: 'int', useNull: true}         
        ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        format: 'json',
        url: '/intake/sap/rates/CountrySpecific',
        actionMethods: {
            create : 'PUT',
            read   : 'GET',
            update : 'PUT',
            destroy: 'PUT'
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever I click "Add Rate" to insert a new record into my store, it calls my proxy and generates a GUID.  However, when I go to click "Update" on that record, there is no ID value - it's just null.  As a result, it just inserts a new record instead of updating the existing one I just created.

So, is there a way to use the `reader` of the proxy to try to update my model with the new ID that was generated?

Or, am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: where is update function?

Comment: Actually, my boss was able to figure this one out - I'll post the solution tomorrow.